# Should I refuse to go to a conference in area that recently had an earthquake?

Tags: travel

My work is paying for me to go to a conference in another city. They've booked the flights et cetera, so they've already invested a lot of money in this.

It's now just a few days out from the conference and the city has had a lot of earthquakes in the last few days. The media is saying it's relatively safe to travel to the area, and the conference organisers are not cancelling the conference, but I'm not convinced of my safety.

Is it reasonable to refuse to go to the conference? Is it ethical for the company to insist I go?

Comment: Have you voiced your concerns to your manager or to HR?

Comment: My relatives in Chch reckon it's ok even though the business district as far away as Wgtn was closed down temporarily. So long as the venue didn't sustain structural damage I see no reason for you not to attend. But you can refuse if you want, and your company cannot force you overtly, although it might make things a bit difficult for you in the future.

Comment: If they've already had a lot of quakes there's no reason not to go--the stored energy is dissipated.

Comment: @LorenPechtel pseudoscience much?

Comment: @djechlin Earthquakes are caused by tension building up on a fault line.  An earthquake is the release of this tension.  While you might get aftershocks soon after a quake they're a lot weaker than the original and it doesn't sound like the original was bad in the first place.

Comment: @LorenPechtel ah, so that's the full pseudoscience explanation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aftershocks_of_April_2015_Nepal_earthquake

Comment: @djechlin Note that only two of those have even 1% of the energy of the initial quake.

Comment: @LorenPechtel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreshock as well as concerns at the time that Nepal *was* the foreshock.

Comment: Why don't just ask the geological service/whatever? If there is increased risk they would tell you. Note that no geological service will ever grant you that there will be no earthquake, what they can tell is if, that as far as they know, the risk is the same as usual (so it is not riskier to go now that it was to go a month ago).

Comment: After 9/11 in the US many companies honored a request to not fly.  Many cancelled non essential air travel.  Earth quake region is not he same magnitude.

Comment: For anyone wondering, I told my employer I wouldn't go. My own manager was ok with it, but the (higher up) manager who had approved the budget for it was not so impressed because "he would have gone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't force you to go. If you are concerned about the expense, perhaps offer the place to someone else instead? Otherwise, considering the conference is still going ahead, I'd say attendees safety should have been considered and the organisers believe it is safe to go. So perhaps think about your options, and make a decision. If you don't want to go, it would be better to tell them sooner rather than later so they can cancel or find a substitute to take your place. Considering that earthquakes are out of your (or anybody's) control, it shouldn't be too much of an issue if you decline based on that.